# Microsoft speech recognizer. How to recognize questions?

Tags: speech-recognition

I'm using Microsoft.Speech recognition engine, and I need a way to know if a user input is a question or not. Is there a way to analyse speech intonation ?

I have read about "POS tagging" and "melodic contour recognition". "POS tagging" seems to be a very difficult search area and I even don't know if there is a way to get "rises" and "fall" of a voice without third-party.

Comment: I suppose you are working on languages other than English. In English questions are easily understood from text grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.Speech.Recognizer engine only supports grammar based recognition, and doesn't support dictation, so you can [tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.semanticresultkey%28v=office.13%29.aspx) the various productions with [data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.semanticresultvalue%28v=office.13%29.aspx) indicating whether it's a question or not.

The System.Speech.Recognizer engine supports dictation, but doesn't pass any speech intonation data back through the API.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Microsoft Speech recognition supports this feature, but you are in luck because you can use English grammar to do a lot of the work for you.

Firstly, look for phrases beginning with what, where, when, why, etc.

A second effective you can use is classifying the part of speech of each word in a sentence. English tends to almost exclusively put verbs in front of subjects in questions only! So if a sentence begins with a verb, it's almost always a question.

Ex

```
You are a good programmer. - statement
```

As opposed to

```
Are you a good programmer? - question
```

So just use a dictionary API to get the part of speech of each word and look if your phrases begin with verbs. You can delineate phrases by looking for pauses in speech or by parsing individual commands themselves.

Alternatively, you could do what I did in my program and use a key phrase such as "Look up:" which triggered a search of Wolfram Alpha. So that statement would "Look up what is the height of the empire state building, and it would." I am not sure about your use case, but that would seem like an effective solution if you want to pass the phrase to Wolfram Alpha or some other natural language search engine.

I hope some of this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft speech recognizer supports [SRGS](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/) grammar. You can create generative grammar templates which could recognize questions. For that I reccomend you to write it in ABNF editor than convert it to SRGS. Since you just need to recognize, if a sentence forms a question, you can use $GARBAGE rule for the slots that will be filled by users.

I wrote a very basic ABNF grammar which might give you more concrete idea, you can convert this code to SRGS with an editor.

```
#ABNF 1.0 UTF-8;

language en-US;
mode voice;
tag-format <semantics/1.0>;

root $IsQuestion;

public $IsQuestion = $WHWords [$GARBAGE] $AuxVerbs [$GARBAGE] {out="yes"};


public $AuxVerbs= (am|is|are|was|were);

public $WHWords=(what|which|where);
```